# Bootstrap Modal Couldn't Refresh the Data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter-3

After closing the modal then opening another modal, the data showed up won't change. I need the data change as it should be. Here's my html for the button:

`<a data-toggle="modal"  title="Quick View" href="#" onclick="detailsmodal(<?= $row->id; ?>)"><i class=" ti-zoom-in"></i><span>Quick Shop</span></a>`

Then this is my Javascript code:

```
function detailsmodal(id) {
    var data = {"id" : id};
    // send data to store_items/detailsmodal
    jQuery.ajax({
        url     : '<?= base_url()?>store_items/detailsmodal',
        method  : "post",
        data    : data,
        success : function(data){
            jQuery('body').append(data);
            jQuery('#details-modal').modal('toggle');


        },
        error   : function(){
            alert("Something went wrong!");
        }
    });
}
```

And this is my store_items/detailsmodal function:

```
function detailsmodal() {

    $item_id = $this->input->post('id', TRUE);
    $query = $this->get_where($item_id);
    foreach ($query->result() as $item) {
        $data['item_title'] = $item->item_title;
    }
    $this->load->view('detailsmodal', $data);
}
```

And the last is the view. The view works fine. The only matter is that it doesn't show the latter data. I don't know where the problem lies. I've been searching here and there and I couldn't find the solution that can solve my problem. Please help.

Comment: if for whatever reason you need to return the page as "string" you need to put the third parameter in `->view` method as `$this->load->view('detailsmodal', $data, true);` and load it into `.html(response)`

Comment: I'm new in Javascript. Please tell me how to load in into `.html(response)`

Comment: @MuhammadAbdurrouf can you show us exactly the value of data in your ajax success function  add `console.log(data)`

Comment: @ArleighHix Yeah. It shows the whole modal dialogue. But I don't know whether it passes the right id or not. What should I do next?

Comment: I also tried to put it right above `jQuery.ajax({`. And it showed the right id.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, it loads correctly the first time, then following attempts to show a different modal are just showing the same modal with the same data.

This is most likely because you are not using a unique `id` for the modal. The first modal that gets added to the DOM with the `id="details-modal"` is the only one that is found by `jQuery('#details-modal')` so it will be that same modal that is shown each time. You could remove the modal from the DOM when it's closed but, you end up repeating ajax calls you have already made when a user re-opens a modal they closed.

Consider adding the `$row->id` to the `id` of the returned modal i.e.`id="details-modal-4"`, then in your javascript  function start by checking to see if you already have the specific modal you need, if not then make the ajax call to get it.

```
function detailsmodal(id) {
    var thisModal = jQuery('#details-modal-' + id);
    if(thisModal.length){
        thisModal.modal('toggle');
    }else{
        var data = {"id" : id};
        // send data to store_items/detailsmodal
        jQuery.ajax({
            url     : '<?= base_url()?>store_items/detailsmodal',
            method  : "post",
            data    : data,
            success : function(data){
                jQuery('body').append(data);
                jQuery('#details-modal-' + id).modal('toggle');


            },
            error   : function(){
                alert("Something went wrong!");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, @arleigh. But, still it doesn't work as I expected. FYI, modal works fine. It can show either id=4 or id=5. The problem is that if at first I opened the id=4 it wouldn't be able to open the id=5. Or vice versa. Actually it can show the data, but the data that showed up is the first clicked modal.

Comment: There appears to be a language barrier, did you read and understand my answer or did you just copy and paste the block of code? Because that is not the whole solution.

Answer (score 0):

data:JSON.stringify(data)

A common use of JSON is to exchange data to/from a web server.

When sending data to a web server, the data has to be a string.

Convert a JavaScript object into a string with JSON.stringify().

Comment: Use it at jQuery.ajax function where you write    (data: data) . Just Replace this (data:JSON.stringify(data)) and check again

Answer (score 0):

I've finally fixed it. I just added this code `jQuery('#details-modal').remove();` right above `jQuery('body').append(data);`, and everything's fine now.